# Getting new PurchId via .NET BusinessConnector

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, business-connector

I am trying to find a .NET BusinessConnector equivalent call for the below line:

```
PurchId = NumberSeq::newGetNum(SalesParameters::numRefSalesId()).num();
```

I am manually entering purchase order information into the purchase order table, which is fine, but the problem lies in the fact that it is the PurchID that ties purchase table (PURCHTABLE) and the individual purchase order lines (PURCHLINE) is the PURCHID field, which is not automatically populated when saving a purchase order.

Currently I am:

```
   ax.TTSBegin();
   axRecord.set_Field("ORDERACCOUNT", purchaseOrder.OrderAccount);
```

(etc)

```
   axRecord.Insert();
```

However, while this will insert a record into the database, it has no purchID, which has to be generated.  You need a purchID to link the purchase line items in.  I found the above code (second line) for X++, but does anyone know of a .NET BusinessConnector call that can be used instead?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a change in the `insert()` method of the `PurchTable` table:

```
if (!purchTable.PurchId)
    purchTable.PurchId = NumberSeq::newGetNum(purchParameters::numRefPurchId()).num();
```

Placed after the `ttsbegin`.

This to avoid complicated C# code. You probably could do it in C# code alone using `CallStaticClassMethod` and cousins, but it is better do put the buisness logic on the X++ side.

See [How to: Call Business Logic Using .NET Business Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa851743%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jan B, thanks for your answer - the link was great. I have managed to get a new purchase ID and do everything else but post the purchase order from .NET code (as we are trying to stick to .NET for the moment). Any idea on posting the PO?

Comment: What do you mean by posting a purchase order? In AX purchase orders are not posted, but packing slips and invoices are.

Comment: Hi, sorry you are right. That did answer the question at hand. Regarding your question - as I understand purchase orders have to be processed or updated or it won't create the respective journal transactions that go along with the PO. That is what I am trying to achieve. If you have any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: What journal transactions are you interested in? I dont't think you can do it from the .Net side, unless you are familiar with the AX sales order data model and operation. You could ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Jan B, thanks for your ongoing support.  Actually, I was able to resolve it - once I could post the Purchase Order, it created the respective journal transactions so all is good.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to execute inside a `TTSBegin`/ `TTSCommit`block, otherwise you will get error error messages [like this one](https://tech.alirazazaidi.com/system-does-not-support-setup-continuous-of-number-sequence-in-ax-2012/).

```
// ax is a reference to an "Axapta" business connector object
var numRef = ax.CallStaticRecordMethod("SalesParameters", "numRefSalesId");
var numSeq = (AxaptaObject)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("NumberSeq", "newGetNum", numRef);
var purchId = numSeq.Call("num");
```